# How do I change the default ringback tone in RestComm?

Tags: sip, voip, mobicents, restcomm

I need to change or remove the default ringback tone in a RestComm instance, or on a per application basis. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently you cannot change the ringback tone per call but you can change the wav file in a Restcomm instance and this will change the ringback for all calls.

The audio wav files are located at $RESTCOMM_HOME/standalone/deployments/restcomm.war/audio/ and there you will find the ringing.wav